# Is it necessary to check whether pid is alive before using it when it passing as paremeter from handle_call?

Tags: elixir

In `erlang`, `pid` parameter become `undefined`, if it died.

Is it necessary to check pid parameter before using it?

The following example is from [Nx](https://github.com/elixir-nx/nx) project, `stream.ex` file. The `receive`, `send`, function doesn't check pid parameter. What's consideration behind these `not check` code?

Is it easy to solve this problem by "let it crash" or    checking parameter outside this module?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In erlang, `pid` parameter become `undefined`, if it died.

This is plain wrong. There is no way any of [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) term to *become* something else, all the terms are immutable. The process might die, though, and then this `pid` would not be pointing to the alive process.

Also, the process cannot simply crash out of the blue. This protocol would be called from somewhere else and I believe in this case it’s the responsibility of the calling entity to make sure these `pid`s are still alive.

Once processes are a part of the supervision tree, they will be restarted after a crash and `pid`s passed here would be pointing the newly created processes.

---

> Is it necessary to check `pid` parameter before using it?

It depends. If this `pid` has been collected and stored ages ago and points to the unrelated process, then the answer would be most likely *yes*. If this is somewhat short-living and/or the caller is responsible for keeping this `pid` in the actual state, then the answer is *no*.